# Fate/GO differences across different language server

Tags: fate-grand-order

Are there any differences between the storyline of English and Chinese Fate/Go from the original Japanese version? Are the stories and events up to date?

Comment: I don't play FGO, but events shouldn't be up to date from JPN version for sure - afaik GL (global ver.) is released later and they don't just increase event frequency to catch up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Japanese FGO is about 2 years ahead of the US version. Event frequency is the same, so therefore many people make event predictions (that turn out correct) about upcoming events in NA.

I believe the CN FGO is 1 year behind the JP version.